# Constructing a reduction between two languages about pairs of Turing machines

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions

I'm curious about a potential relation between the following two languages.

$L_1 := \{\langle M_1, M_2 \rangle : L(M_1) \cap L(M_2) \ne \emptyset \}$.

$L_2  := \{\langle M_1, M_2 \rangle : L(M_1) \ne L(M_2) \}$.

> Is it true that $L_2$ mapping reduces to $L_1$?

I've had many failed attempts to construct a reduction and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three hints.

- Show that $L_2$ is not computably enumerable.
- Show that $L_1$ is computably enumerable.
- If $L_2$ mapping reduces to $L_1$, what does it imply?

Comment: Are you sure that $L_2$ is not computably enumerable?

Comment: Try enumerating the pairs of TMs in $L_2$. You will find you just cannot find a way. Now prove indeed you cannot.

Comment: Of course, if you can show that $L_2$ is not computably enumerable, then there is no such reduction. But could you please prove this? I really don't see why this is true.

Comment: But that language is computably enumerable. It's recognized by the universal Turing machine.

Comment: We can reduce $\overline{HALT}= \{⟨M, w⟩\mid\text{ TM }M\text{does not halt on input } w\}$ to $L_2$.

Comment: Ok, could you please show me the reduction?

Comment: I will let you think for a while. I will come back in half an hour if you cannot figure it out. (In fact, even if you have an oracle to determine the halting problem, $L_2$ is still not enumerable. That is another story, though.)

Comment: It looks like you have figured it out. Great.